# Filter function in ngFor with async variable

Tags: angular

I am trying to filter an array in a ngFor. If I do below I get an error:

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let group of filterGroups(report.assetGroups)">
```

error:
Cannot read property 'assetGroups' of undefined.

If I do following I get another error:

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let group of filterGroups(report?.assetGroups)">
```

error:

TechnicalManagerReportComponent.html:66 ERROR TypeError: _co.filterGroups is not a function

So I am kind of stuck on how to do the filtering. This is my filter function:

```
filterGroups(itemList: AssetGroup[]): AssetGroup[] {
    let result: AssetGroup[] = [];

    return result;
}
```

Notice the ngFor works perfectly without the filter function.

My init method:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe( params => {      
    this.reportId = params.reportId;  

    this.apiService.getReportComplete(this.reportId).subscribe((data) => {    
      this.report = data;
      this.loadGraph(this.report);
    });
  });
}
```

And service:

```
getReportComplete(reportId:string):Observable<ReportComplete>{    
  var url = `https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/reportcomplete/${reportId}`;
  return  this.httpClient.get<ReportComplete>(url).pipe(
    map(x => new ReportComplete(x)));     
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a stackblitz? Is the method `filterGroups` defined in the class `TechnicalManagerReportComponent`?

Comment: I think it will be rather complex to reproduce it as I have a protected REST service.  But yes the method is part of the the TechnicalManagerReportComponent. I think it is the ? that somehow dosen't work as parameter to a function. But if I don't aply that, at the binding stage the next error applies because data is not loaded before rest service has been called and there for report.assetGroups is null at startup.

Comment: Do you have an error if you do `let group of filterGroups(null)`?

Comment: That works: let group of filterGroups(null). So the question is how can you call filterGroups(report?.assetGroups) - with the? Is there another way to parse a nullable proeprty to a filter function.

Comment: To ``report`` variable is assigned some async operation?

Comment: Maybe `filterGroups(report ? report.assetGroups : null)`.

Comment: I updated post with service code.

Comment: OOhh jeez filterGroups(report ? report.assetGroups : null) works. Sometimes simple is just the answer. Thanks a lot, please post an answer. I thought that was exactly what report?.assetGroup would produce.

Comment: Just as a note, I believe it's generally considered bad practice to call component methods within your templates' `*ngIf`/`*ngFor`/etc if you can avoid it, as they'll be executed a lot of times (could lead to performance issues).

Comment: I added a stackblitz to my answer, to show that it should also work with the `?.` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `filterGroups` handles a `null` parameter properly, you can test if `report` is defined and pass `null` if it isn't:

```
*ngFor="let group of filterGroups(report ? report.assetGroups : null)"
```

---

Please note that the original code with the safe navigation operator should also work:

```
*ngFor="let group of filterGroups(report?.assetGroups)"
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2qfi3d) for a demo.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="report">
    <div *ngFor="let group of filterGroups(report.assetGroups)">{{group}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

With provided code you assign something to `report` property after some request so probably initially it's `undefined` or `null` - let's add check for that.

Comment: Why not put the `*ngIf` on the div itself? (edit: never mind!)

Comment: @Jeto - You cannot apply two structural directives on the same element.

Comment: @Jeto https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#one-structural-directive-per-host-element

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I never had to do that in any code of mine. This is a bit of a shame though. My bad.

Comment: It's not a shame it's a learning process though in future maybe you would put those two structural directives together and notice error :)

Comment: @Buczkowski Yeah by "a shame" I meant the fact it's not possible to do that, would kinda make sense from a user's perspective :)